# Font creation for logo

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a template and that template has a logo. The logo is something called "Cream". I really like the way it has been set up. I want the same style with different name. How to do that? The problem is that logo is a .png image and not text. Any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a little vague, but I think what you're asking is how to use a the same font that is in the logo to create any arbitrary text you like.

Assuming this is a font / typeface named "Cream", you'll need to find a copy of the font file online (either free or for purchase; it varies based on what you're looking for) and [use CSS to embed the font](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp).

If you're not able to find the font, it may go by a different name.  I've had some good results with [What the Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) determining a font based on images.